# Is it worthwhile asking a mod to delete this question?

Tags: discussion

I have this question: [Desktop shortcut to Bash script crashes and burns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019464/desktop-shortcut-to-bash-script-crashes-and-burns/1019487?noredirect=1#comment1654937_1019487) which I self answered after a couple hours of research and testing. Then another user posted an answer and in comments (paraphrasing) said "RTFM".

Well I could post "RTFM" as an answer to 90% of the questions in AU.

Anyway the software won't let me delete the Question because "someone worked hard writing an answer".

Do you think it would be worthwhile asking a mod to delete this question for me or just sit back and suffer the harassment?

Comment: "man"-page answers make up for 1/2 my rep :-P

Answer (score 15):

Of course not! Your question is fine and might help someone else with the same error. You're not at fault here, the user who gave you grief is.

Next time flag their comments as rude and abusive (which they were) and try to ignore them.

Comment: Thank you for the affirming answer. I felt I was doing OK by industry standards but also know you are encouraged to delete questions or answers that attract down votes. The other reason is the problem was quickly discovered and fixed on my own without anyone's help so didn't see the point in having it lurking around for a millennium or however long until the next stone age. Ignoring public criticism is easy for politicians supporting a red or blue agenda they don't believe in in the first place. Ignoring criticism for something you work hard at and do believe in is a different story.

Comment: Oh good you just fixed "th typo". Don't delete the comments alluded to here please. That would invalidate this Q&A :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the user already deleted them, but even if they hadn't, I won't keep unpleasant comments around just for a meta discussion. Far better to keep th site clean.

Comment: Yes I see the point in keeping the site clean and not keeping uncomfortable comments around which might encourage others to mimic the behavior. I'm glad you were quick to step in and with your mod-like powers of suggestion the issue was resolved without any mod tools nor me to ask for moderator intervention (if this sentence makes any sense).

Answer (score 5):

I just want to note that I'm being misrepresented here. While I admit I was rude, and I'm sorry for that, I did not suggest RTFM. What I suggested was to check for errors, and when OP responded that they believe in proactive approaches, I said that the only way to proactively catch all errors is to know the minutiae of everything involved, which would need reading the source code (stated somewhat rudely, and again, I'm sorry for that). My consistent stand throughout has been to include checks for errors.

Comment: Apology accepted and all is forgiven. For myself I'm sorry for paraphrasing. Let's let bygones be bygones and go forth to solve other problems in the world we can.